# Attributes was ignored by XST and synplify pro

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

I'm using ISE 14.7 , synplify pro 2013.03 and modelsim 10.2c; now I having a problem about keeping a signal's name after synthesis and place&route in ISE and synplify. I used attribute keep and keep_hierarchy in XST,and syn_keep in synplify pro,but some reg was modified in XST after place&route;and all of reg was modified
in synplify,It seems my attributes was ignored in these tools,my code is in follow,can you help me?

```
attribute keep : string;
attribute keep of wr_adr_ram_1,rd_adr_ram_1 : signal is "true";

attribute keep_hierarchy : string;
attribute keep_hierarchy of Behavioral : architecture is "true";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question & Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines.

Comment: Have you tried syn_preserve on the registers?